# Many To Many Polymorphic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I have many "Sites", and I have multiple user types like "Patient", "Provider", "Nurse", "Administrator", etc.

```
class Patient
  has_many :sites
end

class Provider
  has_many :sites
end

#etc user models...

class Site < ApplicationRecord
  # I don't want to have to name every user model here...
  has_many :patients
  has_many :providers
  has_many :nurses
  # etc. user models...
end
```

What I would like to do, is have it so that each user type can have many sites, and each site can have many of each user type, **but I don't want to do the following because the user type models may increase exponentially...**

I thought maybe I could do a polymorphic relationship, but this doesn't satisfy the many_to_many relationship.

Comment: Maybe you could use **the same strategy** used by the `ActiveStorage`, and set up the table `Site` like the `ActiveStorageAttachment`: there is a column for the `record_type` (Patient, Provider, etc) and a column for the `record_id` (the `id` of the correspondent record of the `record_type` table. This post maybe can give an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50775681/5239030

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use single table inheritance:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance

then your patients, providers, nurses, etc. would all inherit from a base class called something like SiteOwner or similar, which would be the only association on the Site class.

Comment: What we do is we have many user types I.E. Patient, Provider, etc. And we have a User model, in which a User can be many types. Then there is an intermidiary  model called Role. So I.E. User.roles.where(roleable_type: "Patient"). This is why we can't do basic STI, and why the Sites need to be connected to the User type: A Patient may be at one site, but that Patient may be a Provider at another site.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sites_siteables, as: :siteable
  has_many :sites, through: :sites_siteables
end

class Provider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sites_siteables, as: :siteable
  has_many :sites, through: :sites_siteables
end

# this is the join model between Site and Siteable(which is any model)
# you can generate this model by running the command:
# rails g model sites_siteable site:belongs_to siteable:references{polymorphic}
class SitesSiteable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :siteable, polymorphic: true
end

class Site < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sites_siteables
  has_many :patients, through: :sites_siteables, source: :siteable, source_type: 'Patient'
  has_many :providers, through: :sites_siteables, source: :siteable, source_type: 'Provider'
end
```

### Usage

```
Patient.first.sites
# => returns Sites
Provider.first.sites
# => returns Sites

Site.first.patients
# => returns Patients
Site.first.providers
# => returns Providers
```

### Comments

- the above code: `Site` `has_many :patients`, `has_many :providers`, and `has_many :users`, etc... is required and you cannot simply collectively put them all as one `has_many`; i.e. you can't do the following (it will generate an error):

  ```
  # app/models/site.rb
  has_many :siteables, through: :sites_siteables, source: :siteable
  ```

... because if this happens let's say you have `Site.first.siteables`, then the value returnes will be a collection of differeent kinds of Models: i.e.:

```
Site.first.siteables[0] # => returns Provider
Site.first.siteables[1] # => returns Provider
Site.first.siteables[2] # => returns Patient
```

... and this is problematic because there is no single model to represent the query on this, and I guess not compatible with Rails code: i.e. why the following is confusing (at least, in the SQL-string generation side):

```
Site.first.siteables.where(phone_number: '123456')
```

... and is probably why Rails specifically does not allow, and raises an error (on a polymorphic association), and that you are required to specify then the `source_type`:

```
has_many :siteables, through: :sites_siteables, source: :siteable
```

#### However...

If you really intend to not have so many lines of `has_many` in the `Site` model like the following:

```
has_many :patients, through: :sites_siteables, source: :siteable, source_type: 'Patient'
has_many :providers, through: :sites_siteables, source: :siteable, source_type: 'Provider'
has_many :users, through: :sites_siteables, source: :siteable, source_type: 'User'
# ...
# ...
```

... you can create another "Abstract" table/model to represent the polymorphic record (I'll update the answer if you wish so; let me know). i.e. you can do something like the following instead:

```
Site.first.abstract_siteables[0].siteable
# => returns a Patient, or a Provider, or a User, etc...
Site.first.abstract_siteables[1].siteable
# => returns a Patient, or a Provider, or a User, etc...
Site.first.abstract_siteables[2].siteable
# => returns a Patient, or a Provider, or a User, etc...
```